# How should I write RowMapper with other Object dependencies?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbc, dao

### **Introduction**

Here's the deal, let's assume my beans go like this :

```
public class Bean1 {
    private long id;
    private long idBean2;
    private Bean2 bean2;
}

public class Bean2 {
    private long id;
}
```

(Corresponding getters and setters are assumed)

I want to retrieve a **very large number** of Bean1 from my DB with the associated DAO and I'd like it to have Bean2 associated to it. How should I proceed? I have three ideas, all with pros and cons, which one should I go for?

(Autowired, services, JDBC initializations are assumed)

### **Idea 1**

```
public class Bean1Dao {
    public List<Bean1> selectBean1s() {
        String query =
            "SELECT " +
            "  b1.* " +
            "  b2.* " +
            "FROM " +
            "  BEAN1 b1 " +
            "  INNER JOIN BEAN2 b2 ON b1.ID_B2 = b2.ID";

        return jdbcTemplate.query(query, new Bean1Mapper());
    }

    public static class Bean1Mapper implements ParameterizedRowMapper<Bean1> {
        @Override
        public Bean1 mapRow(final ResultSet rs, final int rownum) throws SQLException {
            Bean1 bean1 = new Bean1();
            bean1.setId = rs.getLong("b1.ID");
            bean1.setIdBean2 = rs.getLong("b1.ID_B2");
            try {
                bean1.setBean2 = new Bean2Dao.Bean2Mapper().mapRow(rs, rownum);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Log exception here... Or not
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Bean2Dao {
    public List<Bean2> selectBean2s() {
        String query = "SELECT b2.* FROM BEAN2";
        return jdbcTemplate.query(query, new Bean2Mapper());
    }

    public static class Bean2Mapper implements ParameterizedRowMapper<Bean2> {
        @Override
        public Bean2 mapRow(final ResultSet rs, final int rownum) throws SQLException {
            Bean2 bean2 = new Bean2();
            bean2.setId = rs.getLong("b2.ID");
        }
    }
}
```

**Pros**: 1 SQL query

**Cons**: need to specify the prefix in all SQL queries which is quite-heavy looking and (I'm quite sure) WILL lead to annoying errors due to missing prefixes.

### **Idea 2**

```
public class Bean1Dao {
    public List<Bean1> selectBean1s() {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM BEAN1";
        return jdbcTemplate.query(query, new Bean1Mapper());
    }

    public static class Bean1Mapper implements ParameterizedRowMapper<Bean1> {
        @Override
        public Bean1 mapRow(final ResultSet rs, final int rownum) throws SQLException {
            Bean1 bean1 = new Bean1();
            bean1.setId = rs.getLong("ID");
            bean1.setIdBean2 = rs.getLong("ID_B2");
        }
    }
}
```

In this case, the DAO is not mapping the Bean2 object and the service will have to loop through Bean1 objects and call the Bean2Dao for each object in order to map it using the idBean2 property.

**Pros**: very simple and light-looking queries

**Cons**: very slow to execute (I'm talking about thousand or million objects here, which would mean same amount of DB calls in that case)

### **Idea 3**

```
public class Bean1Dao {
    public Map<Long, Bean1> selectBean1Map() {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM BEAN1";
        List<Bean1> bean1List = jdbcTemplate.query(query, new Bean1Mapper());

        Map<Long, Bean1> bean1Map = new HashMap<Long, Bean1>();
        for (Bean1 bean1 : bean1List) {
            bean1Map.put(bean1.getId(), bean1);
        }
        return bean1Map;
    }

    public static class Bean1Mapper implements ParameterizedRowMapper<Bean1> {
        @Override
        public Bean1 mapRow(final ResultSet rs, final int rownum) throws SQLException {
            Bean1 bean1 = new Bean1();
            bean1.setId = rs.getLong("ID");
            bean1.setIdBean2 = rs.getLong("ID_B2");
        }
    }
}

public class Bean2Dao {
    public Map<Long, Bean2> selectBean2Map() {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM BEAN2";
        List<Bean2> bean2List = jdbcTemplate.query(query, new Bean2Mapper());

        Map<Long, Bean2> bean2Map = new HashMap<Long, Bean2>();
        for (Bean2 bean2 : bean2List) {
            bean2Map.put(bean2.getId(), bean2);
        }
        return bean2Map;
    }

    public static class Bean2Mapper implements ParameterizedRowMapper<Bean2> {
        @Override
        public Bean2 mapRow(final ResultSet rs, final int rownum) throws SQLException {
            Bean2 bean2 = new Bean2();
            bean2.setId = rs.getLong("ID");
        }
    }
}
```

Here the service needs to loop through the bean1Map to assign the objects from the bean2Map.

**Pros**: n queries and light looking DAOs (n beign the number of Bean1's members to look for in the DB (here n = 1 but it's bigger in my case))

**Cons**: n queries (idea 1 has only 1 query)

### Conclusion

I'm not quite sure which solution to adopt. Maybe I'm missing another better solution or maybe there is a standard I'm missing that defines how things should be done.
I would greatly appreciate any input on this.

TL;DR: How should I retrieve an Object from DB and link its members that are also in DB in the case of a **very large** amount of data?

Comment: Approximately how many is a "very large number"?

Comment: from 10.000 to 1.000.000 and it can still grow bigger again. So, ok, depending on the context it can be a small number, but in terms of looping-on-that-number-to-do-SQL-queries, it is big.

Answer (score 1):

Do you absolutely need all of your beans in your memory at a single point in time?

My advice: Go for option **1** - even if you'll have to prefix your stuff.

**Con:** Time to code your SQL (one-time effort)

**Pro:**

- Performance: You claim you have a very large number of rows. Say 1.000.000 rows. Think about the cost of 1.000.000 additional SQL roundtrips (these include Network-I/O so are measured in milliseconds). You easily add **thousands of seconds aka hours** of execution time to your code that way.
- Memory footprint: All of your bean objects. Cannot be helped.

Option **3** looks promising as well - but you add 1.000.000 additional lookups plus the additional SQL statement into your map to your code.

By the way: You only need *one* map if you put `bean1Map.put(bean1.getIdBean2(), bean1);` and later in bean2 loop find the matching `bean1` and set `bean2`...

Comment: Yeah I kind of like this solution too.

The end goal is to display stuff from both beans in one export file. So in practice, I need both beans in memory.

But even with that taken apart, I'm wondering what is the good practice to make that scalable and generalizable to other DAOs.

Comment: In that case you **really** want to go down lane 1 - and export the items as you come across them rather than filling up your memory with **all** objects (solution #3) and then doing the export.

Comment: Hm yeah but isn't it considered bad practice to link DAOs between them in a conception perspective? That, plus the prefixes, it feels very _wrong_

Comment: Creating objects to export data maybe isn't where DAO are at their strongest. About the prefixes - ever seen what hibernate does to fetch some linked objects? Looks awful, but works great.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say if the goal was memory efficiency, fast execution, or minimal programming. I would use option 1 if you are looking for memory efficiency.

You may improve execution time for any of the approaches by using multiple threads. Each thread would need to select a subset of the rows to be processed.

If you are open to using another library, I recommend [sormula](http://www.sormula.org) that I authored. You can use [ScalarSelectOperation](http://www.sormula.org/javadoc/org/sormula/operation/ScalarSelectOperation.html) or [SelectIterator](http://www.sormula.org/javadoc/org/sormula/operation/SelectIterator.html) to read one Bean1 at a time. Sormula will perform the cascade select for Bean2. Sormula will use only 2 prepared JDBC statements, one for Bean1 table and one for Bean2 table.

Comment: I was interested in the general good practices. I'm looking for the most accurate design of DAO, how it should be written in theory. I'm going to post an answer to the post real soon to explain what I chose and why.